# Input parameter for python

Tags: python

I am new to Python.Below is part of my python script

```
if( len(sys.argv) < 2 ):
    print "Please provide the SDK version!"
    print "Usage: python parse.py <sdk_version>"
    sys.exit(2)

sdk_version = sys.argv[1]
timestamp = int( time.time() )
created_on = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime( '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y' )
```

The input command I am giving is "python parse.py 8". But it is giving below error:

> File "parse.py", line 10
>       print "Please provide the SDK version!"
>                                             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What should be correct input.

Comment: Indentation matters in python and you should not mix tab and spaces.That is you have not provided any indentation at all

Comment: Which version of Python is python using? (the REPL usually shows this in startup)

Comment: Yes it is start up. Python 3.4 i am using. I want to know that what input parameter do i need to pass. When i comment the argument check then script runs well

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 requires parentheses for `print`: `print("Hello!")`

Answer (score 1):

`SyntaxError` means that there is a syntax error: In python3 there no longer is a `print` statement, instead there is a `print` function (that need to be called).

You should use `print` function instead of trying to use the `print` statement (note the parentheses around the text to be printed):

```
if( len(sys.argv) < 2 ):
    print("Please provide the SDK version!")
    print("Usage: python parse.py <sdk_version>")
    sys.exit(2)

sdk_version = sys.argv[1]
timestamp = int( time.time() )
created_on = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime( '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y' )
```